# Is this a safe/strong input sanitization function?

Tags: php, mysql, sanitization

This is the sanitization function used in a book I recently learned from - [Sams Teach Yourself Ajax, JavaScript, and PHP All in One](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672329654).

I've been using it on my own PHP site. Is it safe for real-world usage?

```
function sanitizestring($var)
{
  $var = strip_tags($var);
  $var = htmlentities($var);
  $var = stripslashes($var);
  return mysql_real_escape_string($var);
}
```

Comment: Man this book is indeed terrible. It's author don't have a clue. If the rest of this book is the same, you will get no knowledge but ignorance .

Comment: I mentioned the wrong book in the question.  But to be fair the author didn't specify that the function was an all-purpose or general purpose function.   And for a beginner's book I don't expect to become a php god.  I'm open to recommendations :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [the holy grail of cleaning input and output in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810869/the-holy-grail-of-cleaning-input-and-output-in-php)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would say that is too general. It *may* be safe for a lot of uses, but it would often give unwanted side affects to strings. Not every string should be escaped like that.

- `mysql_real_escape_string()` should be used within SQL queries only. Better still, bind params with PDO.
- Why would you want to blanket strip tags and encode entities before inserting into a database? Maybe do it on the way out.
- For XSS prevention, `htmlspecialchars()` is more of your friend. Give it the character set as an argument.

So I would use `mysql_real_escape_string()` for queries, and `htmlspecialchars()` for echoing user submitted strings. There is also a lot more to know. Do some [further reading](http://shiflett.org/blog/2005/jan/xss-cheatsheet).

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider [filter-input](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) with those [filters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-list.php) applied to this [scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input-array.php).