# The holy grail of cleaning input and output in php?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json

I've been running and developed a classified site now for the last 8 months and all the bugs were due to only one reason: how the users input their text...

**My question is**: Is there a php class, a plugin, something that I can do

`$str = UltimateClean($str)` before sending $str to my sql??

PS. I also noticed the problems doubled when i started using JSON, because I also have to be careful outputting the result in JSON..

Some issues I faced: multi-language strings (different charsets), copy-paste from Excel sheets. 

Note: I am not worried for SQL Injections.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is this a safe/strong input sanitization function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597412/is-this-a-safe-strong-input-sanitization-function) or [Is htmlentities() and mysql_real_escape_string() enough for cleaning user input in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632663/is-htmlentities-and-mysql-real-escape-string-enough-for-cleaning-user-input) or any of the other [search results](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php%20general%20escaping%20function). Your JSON inquiry needs elaboration.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, there isn't.

Different modes of escaping are for different purposes.  You cannot universally escape something.

**For Databases:**  Use [PDO with prepared queries](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html#10)

**For HTML:**  Use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

**For JSON:**  [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) handles this for you

**For character sets:**  You should be using UTF-8 on your page.  Do this, and set your databases accordingly, and watch those issues disappear.

Comment: perhaps also, consider a library like ckeditor etc. for text input. These can help handle the paste-from-word scenario, BUT it is client-side.

Comment: I think I said "help" and anyway, JSON implies client-side, and the OP suggests that user input is part of the issue.

Comment: +1 for "You cannot universally escape something". If you feel the need for "universal escaping", you're probably escaping your input too early, or reusing escaped data for a purpose that it wasn't meant for.