# Proper way to sanitize ALL posted fields?

Tags: php, forms, post, escaping, sanitize

I'm new to sanitizing input data, but we are starting to ramp up with number of clients very quickly, so we will need to have all user inputs sanitized, just in case, as it's a best practice.

If I've got a form that posts 12 fields, what's the best and least expensive way to sanitize it?

for simplicity's sake let's say I've got

```
$one = $_POST['one'];
$two = $_POST['two'];
$three = $_POST['three'];
$four = $_POST['four'];
$five = $_POST['five'];
```

**EDIT:**
right here - This is getting inserted into a database under metadata. I then call to

Then I'm just calling

```
printf('The input for One is ' .$theNewVarForOne. '!');
```

But there IS a potential for malicious code in there. What's the best way to strip all iffy inputs?

**EDIT:**

I should have been more specific. I am basically creating some 'post' data that is stored in a database. A title, the date, the body, etc.

Comment: See my answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/7810880/362536  Don't escape your data early.  If you are outputting variable data (user-provided or not!) use `htmlspecialchars()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are printing to the screen, then HTMLspecialchars should be fine:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['one']);
```

It converts any potential malicious javascript and HTML into characters like `&lt;` so that it displays as text in your source code (meaning it cannot be executed) and to the user it looks like the original input displayed on the screen:

```
<?php
$new = htmlspecialchars("<a href='test'>Test</a>", ENT_QUOTES);
echo $new; // &lt;a href=&#039;test&#039;&gt;Test&lt;/a&gt;
?>
```

If you are on the other hand inserting into a database, then you will need to do some extra work.

When inserting into a database, you really need to use prepared statements (this will stop anyone doing anything funky with SQL to your database). I prefer to use [PDO](http://au.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to make my connection.

The code will look like this (snipped from the docs on [prepare](http://au.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)):

```
<?php
/* Execute a prepared statement by passing an array of values */
$sql = 'SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour';
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
$sth->execute(array(':calories' => 150, ':colour' => 'red'));
$red = $sth->fetchAll();
$sth->execute(array(':calories' => 175, ':colour' => 'yellow'));
$yellow = $sth->fetchAll();
?>
```

Comment: First of all, one shouldn't send any output on a POST in the first place. Second, doing htmlspecialchars() on a POST variable is pointless. A hacker gains nothing from injecting JavaScript into a page that he himself would see. The emphasis should be on making sure that text that has already been saved into the database is properly escaped. That's where JavaScript injection could lead to session-hijacking.

Answer (score 0):

If you are inserting it into a database, I recommend you to use the Fluffeh's method, but a dirty quick work around is to use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Comment: Don't do this... go the prepared query route.  That way, mistakes do not happen.