# XSS attacks, multiple html sanitization

Tags: html, database, security, xss

I'm working on a web service project, where I display some data obtained from database, which in turn is made of users' inputs. Of course I want to prevent my application from being vulnerable to XSS attacks, so obviously I sanitize the input from html special characters. But I have a following problem - data returned from the server is in form < (in this example case for '<' sign), and on the front end the second sanitization process occurs, making it &lt;, which is totally incomprehensible by the web browser. Is there a simple way to get over it, or maybe I should sanitize inputs only in one place (I presume that the server would be the best option).

Thanks for all answers.

Comment: which server you are using ?

Comment: it's spring boot, and to sanitize the html I use spring's htmlEscape function

Comment: See this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/7810880/362536

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't reliably sanitize user input. It's a losing battle. As soon as you think you've filtered out all the "bad" characters, someone will pass in an escape sequence or something else unexpected

If you're using a database server, make sure all input is handled by pre-compiled stored procedures, and make sure that the user that the web app logs in as, only has EXECUTE perms. This prevents SQL injection and other mischief.

If you're worried about actual characters, make sure you have a "pass through OK characters" filter and not a "remove bad characters" filter. The number of "good characters" is finite, while the number of attack vectors is infinite.

As for your question about "<" characters, if the intended output is for user display, you can run the entire string through HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode or it's equivalent in whatever language you use. This will convert the string into code that will display properly in the browser but not be interpreted.

It doesn't look like you're having a problem escaping it, it looks like you're having a problem deciding if you need to escape it. Pick a standard and stick with it, then convert as necessary. If it normally comes in unescaped, just store it that way, and escape it when you want to display it.

Comment: Thanks for this elaborate answer. I'm currently escaping the characters by a spring method, but the problem lies in multiple escaping, both on the backend and frontend. So '&' is escaped as &amp; which makes the sanitized string not renderable (only &amp; is correctly parsed to '&'). Do you know of an easy way to get over this problem, or do I have to code it myself?

Answer (score -1):

The best way to sanitize untrusted data that is served back to a user in the context of XSSs for spring boot is to use a template engine that will suit your needs (e.g. JSP).

Template engine will automatically generate HTML you need, escape it properly and insert the content in a required placeholder (if an issue with broken encoding occurs for async requests).
**Be careful** and check if a chosen engine does it by default or it needs a special directive to do so.